# Unity. Эффект Dolly Zoom

Tags: unity3d

Я новичок в разработке на Unity и сейчас просто эксперементирую со все возможными графичискими эффектами, и какое то время назад наткнулся на эффект Dolly zoom и по этой теме нашел гайды но они все на английском и единственным что было на русском это документация от самой юнити. Но и там смотрев я мало что понял. Кто может обьяснить что там да как? К слову этот эффект я хочу воссоздать на 2D.

Answer (score 0):

## Для 2d и 3d / Perspective камеры

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    private Camera _camera;

    public bool DollyZoomEnabled;

    private float _initHeightAtDist;

    void Start()
    {
        _camera = transform.GetComponent<Camera>();

        StartDZ();
    }

    // Calculate the frustum height at a given distance from the camera.
    float FrustumHeightAtDistance(float distance)
    {
        return 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(_camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    }

    // Calculate the FOV needed to get a given frustum height at a given distance.
    float FOVForHeightAndDistance(float height, float distance)
    {
        return 2.0f * Mathf.Atan(height * 0.5f / distance) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }

    // Start the dolly zoom effect.
    void StartDZ()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);
        _initHeightAtDist = FrustumHeightAtDistance(distance);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (DollyZoomEnabled)
        {
            // Measure the new distance and readjust the FOV accordingly.
            var currDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);
            _camera.fieldOfView = FOVForHeightAndDistance(_initHeightAtDist, currDistance);
        }

        // Simple control to allow the camera to be moved in and out using the up/down arrows.
        transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }
}
```

просто

1. вешаешь скрипт на камеру
2. присваиваешь плеера в переменную плеер в инспекторе
3. отдаляешь камеру

основано на https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DollyZoom.html

> там ошибки в коде были, я их исправил и доработал скрипт

Для большей реалистичности я бы советовал добавить еще Lens Blur (то есть blur зависящий от дистанции).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Для 2d / orthographic камеры

Для orthographic камеры нужно будет:

1. скейлить обьекты
2. двигать по оси Y
3. Двигать по оси X в стороны в зависимости от того на сколько близко к плееру находится

по некой формуле в зависимости от их дистанции от камеры. Это в реализации дольше и сложнее.

Важный нюанс: Бэкграунд должен быть из множества мелких обьектов. С большими бэкграундами на весь экран точно не сработает.

Comment: Для ортографической камеры нельзя сделать dolly zoom. Этот эффект работает только для перспективы. У ортограческой камеры даже нет фокусного расстояния, что уже напрочь убивает реализацию такого эффекта.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker уверяю что подобие долли зума сделать можно и на ортограческой камере)

Comment: А я уверяю, что нельзя. Смена скейлов объектов, разумеется, будет походить на долли, но это лишь жалкая пародия.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А ничего что 2д лишь жалкая пародия на 3d ?)))

Comment: А для чистого 2д такой эффект и не применяют просто потому что там не используют перспективную камеру, да и особо негде такой эффект применить.

Comment: ну подправил описание так что б была менее жалкая пародия) В реализации сложнее, но выглядеть в 2D будет достаточно близко к dolly.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker на тему того что в 2д может выглядеть как какашка... В общем-то это было сделано в 3д и при помощи перспективной камеры, но по-факту для восприятия это еще хуже чем 2д )) А все равно чувствуется эфект долли. https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0jc0kptq1t1hp3/Noice.7z?dl=0

Comment: Никто и не спорит, что долли можно "имитировать" в 2д, проблема в том, что вся "магия" такого эффекта в перспективе и трехмерности объектов. В 2д такое не делают, потому что это выглядит просто странно.Такой эффект в целом нарушает восприятие и ориентацию в пространстве камеры зрителя, а то, что и в 3д можно сделать плохо - понятное дело :)